# Complete code for picking date in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate Walmart site through selenium webdriver, url - https://www.walmart.com/lists/create-wedding-registry. My question is how to code date picking in java
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kji1N.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fairly straightforward scenario for WebDriver - roughly, you'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
// First find the button that makes the date-picker element appear and click it.
driver.findElement(By.id("event-date-picker-input")).click();

// Then get hold of all the available dates.
List<WebElement> dateList = driver.findElement(By.className("dp_daypicker")).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

// Finally, iterate over all the available dates and click the one with the desired date.
for (WebElement date : dateList) {
   if (date.getText().equals(whateverDateYouWant)) {
      date.click();
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following ways :

Approach one

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WalmartDatePicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\ImpFolder\\SeleniumJar\\chromedriver_win32 (1)");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/lists/create-wedding-registry");

        // first click inside the Event date it will make date picker to appear 

        driver.findElement(By.id("event-date-picker-input")).click();

// how to select next month from the date picker 
      // selecting month 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_next']")).click(); // will move to april one more click to may and so on


        // now how to select a specific date form the calendar
        // prints complete content of the calendAr
        // plz think calendar as a web table with a column and row
        // hence there are 7 tr in source so select an value make ur spath like below
        // for row1 = xpath will be like Xpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[1]/th"))
        List<WebElement> completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));
        for(int i = 0;i<completecalContent.size();i++){
            System.out.println("contents for 1st tr is  : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
        }
        // for row2 = xpath will be like Xpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[2]/td"))
        completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[2]/td"));
        for(int i = 0;i<completecalContent.size();i++){
            System.out.println("contents for 2nd tr is  : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
        }
        // for row3 = xpath will be like Xpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[3]/td"))  and so on
        completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[3]/td"));
        for(int i = 0;i<completecalContent.size();i++){
            System.out.println("contents for 3rd tr is  : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
        }

        // now selecting a specific date .suppose want to select future date say 28 march 2016.
        // u can say that by seeing tr it lies in the 6th tr in source code hence xpath will be 
        // for row6 = xpath will be like Xpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]"))  here td is one as 28 is first td
        completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]"));
        for(int i = 0;i<completecalContent.size();i++){
            System.out.println("contents for 6th tr is  : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());

            // to select simply use 
            if(completecalContent.get(i).getText().equals("28")){
                completecalContent.get(i).click();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Approach Two

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WalmartDatePicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\ImpFolder\\SeleniumJar\\chromedriver_win32 (1)");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/lists/create-wedding-registry");

        // first click inside the Event date it will make date picker to appear 

        driver.findElement(By.id("event-date-picker-input")).click();

        // now how to select a specific date form the calendar
 // selecting month 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_next']")).click(); // will move to april one more click to may and so on

        List<WebElement> completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr/td"));
        for(int i = 0;i<completecalContent.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Print complete Content : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
            if(completecalContent.get(i).getText().equals("28")){
                completecalContent.get(i).click();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Raj, Thank you so much for your valuable response, I tried     List<WebElement> date = d.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dp_daypicker']/tbody/tr/td"));
         for(int i = 0;i<date.size();i++){
          
          // System.out.println("Print complete Content : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
             if(date.get(i).getText().equals("1")){
                 date.get(i).click();
             }
           }    This actually helped in picking a date from current month(march), however if I want to pick from future months, how to do that. Please advise.

Comment: its very easy ,plz look at the updated answer. and if this was the solution you was looking for please marked it as an answer for your question.thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Raj.. This actually helped me.. Thanks

Comment: your welcome please mark it  as answer for your question