# Trying to get website calendar data using Selenium in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get all the calendar data split by unavailable and available for this month and next month. I've had no luck in getting the split. Below are the codes I've used. I'm either able to get all the dates without the attribute to identify whether those dates are available or unavailable, or when I try to iterate I get an error "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM"

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4660676'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/main/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/button'))
)
element.click()
#This one gets me all the dates 
#listitems=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[35]/table/tbody/tr[5]')

#If I try something like the following to then be able to get get_attribute then I get the error mentioned above
#available=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')
#for i in available: print i.text
```

What would be the way to get the dates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to understand to be able to fix it:

- the datepicker appears right on the button click, but it takes time to load - wait for it
- to determine which of the days is available and not, use the presence of the `ui-datepicker-unselectable` class

Implementation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4660676'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# click "Instant Book"
book = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[span = "Instant Book"]'))
)
book.click()

# wait for datepicker to load
wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ui-datepicker:not(.loading)'))
)

days = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td")
for cell in days:
    day = cell.text.strip()
    if not day:
        continue

    if "ui-datepicker-unselectable" in cell.get_attribute("class"):
        status = "Unavailable"
    else:
        status = "Available"

    print(day, status)
```

Prints:

```
1 Unavailable
2 Unavailable
3 Unavailable
4 Unavailable
5 Unavailable
6 Unavailable
7 Unavailable
8 Unavailable
9 Unavailable
10 Unavailable
11 Unavailable
12 Unavailable
13 Unavailable
14 Unavailable
15 Unavailable
16 Unavailable
17 Unavailable
18 Unavailable
19 Unavailable
20 Unavailable
21 Unavailable
22 Unavailable
23 Unavailable
24 Unavailable
25 Unavailable
26 Unavailable
27 Unavailable
28 Available
29 Available
30 Unavailable
31 Unavailable
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I guess I had 3 follow-up questions: (1) why is css selector better to get the dates? (2) how would I click the next month button, because when I inspect it doesn't look like a button <a class="ui-datepicker-next icon icon-chevron-right ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"></span></a> (3) Is there a way to pull out that months value so that you'd get something like Month Day Availability

Comment: @FancyDolphin (1) it is not necessarily better (though a lot of people would say so), but it's generally more concise and faster (depending on the browser) (2) the `a` links at the top of the calendar are to change the month, right (3) well, you already know the days, the month is here: `<span class="ui-datepicker-month">March</span>` - depending on what you are trying to do next, loading the dates into date/datetime objects might be beneficial..though this is probably a part of a different question..Thanks.

Comment: Once again thanks for helping me with my rookie questions

Comment: plz have a look at this its in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182791/complete-code-for-picking-date-in-selenium-webdriver/36221527?noredirect=1#comment60079086_36221527

Comment: @alecxe The last follow-up to this if I have another clickable like this: element = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]'))
) element.click() it gives me an error element is not clickable. The only to get around this is to put driver.refresh() and it works. do you have any workarounds?